# WebGL: How to overlay a moving texture on top of another texture?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, textures

For an honors credit independent class project I need to use WebGL to display an image of my choosing that I use as textures and then morph the texture to make it look like it is moving or changing in some way.

To do this, I chose to morph a raindrop texture to make it seem like raindrops are falling down the screen. I have a landscape background texture (a .jpg image), and I want to overlay that with a raindrop texture ( a .png image), but I am not sure how to overlay the background texture so that I can see both images at the same time. The code that I have right now is only showing the background image.

Can anyone help explain to me what I am doing wrong, and how I could go about fixing this? If you need me to upload part of my code to look at let me know. I barely understand WebGL, so I don't know what area of my code to show in order to see where I am going wrong. for all I know, the entire thing could be wrong.

EDIT: I was told to add code, so since I don't know what snippet to show, here is my entire javascript and html files:

PLEASE ALSO NOTE: This code only works in FireFox! Google Chrome will give an error! (though I think it will give an error regrardless, because I did not give the files referenced in the .html file)*

```js
var canvas;
var gl;

var Index = 0;

var texCoord = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0),
    vec2(0, 0)
];

var vertices = [
    vec2( -1, -1 ),
    vec2(  -1,  1 ),
    vec2(  1, 1 ),
    vec2( 1, 1 ),
    vec2(  1,  -1 ),
    vec2(  -1, -1 )
];

var pointsArray = [];

//PROGRAMS
var program1; //for background
var program2; //for rain texture
var program3; //for rain texture updates


//TEXTURES
var texture1; //background image (STATIC IMAGE)
var texture2; // Raindrop texture (bounce between 2 and 3)
var texture3; // Raindrop texture (transform to be sent between 2 and 3)


//BUFFERS--------------------------------------------------------------------
var framebuffer; 

var buffer1; //buffer for static background (texture1) vertices
var buffer2; //buffer for static background (texture1) texcoordinates
var buffer3; //buffer for raindrops (texture2) vertices
var buffer4; //buffer for raindrops (texture2) texcoordinates
var buffer5; //buffer for texture3 vertices
var buffer6; //buffer for texture3 texcoordinates


window.onload = function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//BACKGROUND texture
texture1 = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
 
// Fill the texture with a blue screen (fill canvas) FILLER!!!
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 2048, 1024, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));
 
// load image

    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL,1);

    // Get the IMG tag by its ID
    var bgpic = document.getElementById("background");

    
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
 
    // Load data from the IMG
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, bgpic);
 
 gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
//RAINDROP TEXTURE
texture2 = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
 
// Fill the texture with a blue screen (fill canvas) FILLER!!!
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 2048, 1024, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));
 
// load image

    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL,1);

    // Get the IMG tag by its ID
    var rainPic = document.getElementById("raindrop");

    
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
 
    // Load data from the IMG
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, rainPic);
 
 gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//EMPTY TEXTURE TO PASS TEXTURE2 TO
 texture3 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2 );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 2048, 1024, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE ); 
 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
// Allocate a frame buffer object

   framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
   framebuffer.width = 4096;
   framebuffer.height = 2048;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Attach color buffer

   gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1, 0);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// check for completeness

   var status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
   if(status != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) alert('Frame Buffer Not Complete');
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    program1 = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader1", "fragment-shader1" );
 program2 = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader2", "fragment-shader2" );
    program3 = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader3","fragment-shader3");
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//PROGRAM 1 CODE
    gl.useProgram( program1 );
  
     gl.useProgram(program1);
        
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    
    // send data to GPU for normal render
        
    buffer1 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer1);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,   flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program1, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    buffer2 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoord), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    var vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation( program1, "vTexCoord"); 
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord );
 
    gl.uniform1i( gl.getUniformLocation(program1, "texture1"), 0);
 
 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
 
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); 
    gl.viewport(0, 0, 2048, 1024);
 
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
   
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

//PROGRAM 2 CODE
 gl.useProgram(program2);

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
 
    buffer3 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer3 );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program2, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    // Bind FBO and render
    
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

                  
    gl.viewport(0, 0, 2048, 1024);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    
//    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);

    // Bind to window system frame buffer, unbind the texture
    
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
//PROGRAM 3 CODE 
    gl.useProgram(program3);
        
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture3);
    
    // send data to GPU for normal render
        
    buffer5 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer5);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,   flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program3, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    buffer6 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer6);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoord), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    var vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation( program3, "vTexCoord"); 
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord );
 
    gl.uniform1i( gl.getUniformLocation(program3, "texture2"), 0);
 
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); 
    gl.viewport(0, 0, 2048, 1024);
   
    
    render();
    
}


function render() {

   // render to texture
   
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // SECTION FOR BACKGROUND TEXTURE!
 //BACKGROUND TEXTURE: USE PROGRAM 1
 gl.useProgram(program1);  
    
 gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );      
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );
    
    gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null); 
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
            
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );      
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
 
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//RAIN TEXTURE: USE PROGRAM 2 
 gl.useProgram(program2);
   
    gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    
    if(flag) {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
        gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture3, 0);

    }
    else {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture3);
        gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2, 0);

    }
   
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// RAIN TEXTURE: USE PROGRAM 3
 
    gl.useProgram(program3);
    
    
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );
    
    gl.bindFramebuffer( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null); 
    if(flag) gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    else gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
            
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );      
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    
    flag = !flag
    
    requestAnimFrame(render);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script id="vertex-shader1" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;

varying vec2 fTexCoord;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
 fTexCoord= vTexCoord;
} 
</script>

<script id="vertex-shader2" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;

attribute vec2 vTexCoord;

varying vec2 fTexCoord;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
 fTexCoord= vTexCoord;

} 
</script>

<script id="vertex-shader3" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;

varying vec2 fTexCoord;

void main()
{

 gl_Position = vPosition;
 fTexCoord = vTexCoord;

}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader1" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

varying vec2 fTexCoord;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor= texture2D(texture1, fTexCoord);
}

</script>

<script id="fragment-shader2" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D texture2;

varying vec2 fTexCoord;

void main()
{
 gl_FragColor= texture2D(texture2, fTexCoord);

}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader3" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying  vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main() 
{ 
 float y= fTexCoord.y - 0.1;
 float x= fTexCoord.x;
 
 if(y < 0.0) {
  y = 1.0;
  x = fTexCoord.x + 0.1 ;
 }
 if(x > 1.0){
  x = 0.0;
 }
 
 gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture2, vec2(x,y));         

} 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/InitShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="testingBG.js"></script>

<img src="Raindrops_scaled.png" id="raindrop" hidden />
<img src="Background.jpg" id="background" hidden />

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="2048" height="1024">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should also include code and output into your post.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to supply a more comprehensive explaination of what might go into a solution that wold work for you.

This might not work in chrome because of cors >.>

edit: Got around cors by manually insering images as bitmap arrays. T.T

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
   
   img {
    display: none;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  // I've only placed this here to get around cors < _ >
  var images = function() {
   
   "use strict";
   
   function Image(width,height,pixels) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.pixels = pixels;
   }
   
   return {
    background: new Image(16,16,new Uint8Array([127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,95,95,95,255,95,95,95,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,95,95,95,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,95,95,95,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,95,95,95,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,95,95,95,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,95,95,95,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,95,95,95,255,95,95,95,255,95,95,95,255,153,217,234,255,95,95,95,255,127,127,127,255,127,127,127,255,95,95,95,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,95,95,95,255,95,95,95,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,22,116,50,255,22,116,50,255,22,116,50,255,22,116,50,255,22,116,50,255,22,116,50,255,22,116,50,255,22,116,50,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,153,217,234,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255,34,177,76,255])),
    raindrop: new Image(8,8,new Uint8Array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,41,49,151,255,41,49,151,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,41,49,151,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,41,49,151,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,41,49,151,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,41,49,151,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,41,49,151,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,41,49,151,255,0,0,0,0,41,49,151,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,41,49,151,255,41,49,151,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,41,49,151,255,0,0,0,0,41,49,151,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,64,73,202,255,41,49,151,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,41,49,151,255,41,49,151,255,41,49,151,255,41,49,151,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]))
   };
   
  }();
  
  void function() {
   
   "use strict";
   
   // Variables
   var canvasWidth = 180;
   var canvasHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var gl = null;
   var raindrops = [];
   
   // WebGL programs (contains code that modifies your vertex data & code that processes each pixel)
   var backgroundProgram = null;
   var raindropProgram = null;
   
   // WebGL program attributes (indexes into attributes inside the program, webgl uses these to interpret data in the buffers)
   var aPositionLocation = 0;
   var aUVLocation = 1;
   
   // WebGL program uniforms (It's a variable that's shared between Javascript and the program, you just need to call a function to update it's value)
   var uRaindropPosition = null; // vec2
   var uRaindropSize = null; // vec2
   
   // WebGL buffers (It's like an array '[]', but it's on the GPU, we'll use it here to specify the properties of triangles we want to draw)
   var backgroundBuffer = null;
   
   // WebGL textures
   var backgroundTexture = null;
   var raindropTexture = null;
   
   // Constructors
   // If this function is called with 'new Raindrop(0,0,10);' it'll create a new raindrop object that has these properties
   function Raindrop(x,y,size) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
   }
   
   // Functions
   function createProgram(vertexCode,fragmentCode) {
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    
    // Upload source code
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader,vertexCode);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentCode);
    
    // Compile shaders
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
    
    // Check there isn't any problems
    try {
     if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw "Vertex Shader: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);
     }
     
     if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw "Fragment Shader: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);
     }
    } catch(log) {
     gl.deleteProgram(program);
     gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
     gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
     console.error(log);
    }
    
    // Attach to the main program
    gl.attachShader(program,vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
    gl.deleteShader(fragmentShader);
    
    return program;
   }
   
   function createBuffer(data) {
    // Create a GPU buffer, it's a really simple object
    // Buffers can be best thought of as a normal array that sits in GPU memory (VRAM)
    var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    
    // attach our new buffer on the gpu to 'ARRAY_BUFFER'
    // Think of it as, whatever is attached to 'ARRAY_BUFFER' is the current buffer that get used with WebGl functions
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
    
    // Upload our array of verticies as 32 bit floats
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(data),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    // Tell WebGL we're not using the buffer anymore at the moment
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,null);
    
    return buffer;
   }
   
   function createTexture(image) {
    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    
    // attach our new texture on the gpu to 'TEXTURE_2D'
    // Think of it as, whatever is attached is our current texture we're using for webgl functions
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    
    // Set texture parameters, i.e. how are we going to scale it up or down/ what should happen if we
    // try to get a pixel from outside the texture
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST); // Use nearest neighbour when sizing up
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST); // Use nearest neighbour when sizing down
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.REPEAT); // Apply a modulo to x coordinates if there outside the texture
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.REPEAT); // Apply a modulo to y coordinates if there outside the texture
    
    // Upload our image to our gpu texture
    gl.texImage2D(
     gl.TEXTURE_2D, // I want it to get uploaded to what's attached to TEXTURE_2D
     0, // Mipmap level, it can stay at 0
     gl.RGBA, // Data format the gpu texture will use, in this case 8 bit RGBA for each pixel
     image.width,
     image.height,
     0, // Border, always should be zero
     gl.RGBA, // The data format of the image we're uploading to the gpu
     gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // Datatype of each actual colour channel, here it's going to be an unsigned 8 bit int that will go from 0-255
     image.pixels // The image we finally want to upload!, any HTML image element will work just fine
    );
    
    // Now we'll unbind the texture since we are done with it now
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null); // Passing null tells WebGL that we're not currently 'using' any texture
    
    return texture;
   }
   
   // Convert from Javascript canvas coordinate system to WebGL's normalized device coordinates
   /*
    The position 0,0 moves to the center of the screen.
    The top left corner becomes -1,1
    The bottom right corner becomes 1,-1
    
    Coordinates need to be converted before they can be passed to WebGL
   */
   function convertXCoordinate(x) {
    return (x / canvasWidth) * 2.0 - 1.0;
   }
   
   function convertYCoordinate(y) {
    return ((canvasHeight - y) / canvasHeight) * 2.0 - 1.0;
   }
   
   function loop() {
    // Update
    
    // Update raindrop positions
    // Just to simulate rain 'falling'
    for (var i = 0; i < raindrops.length; ++i) {
     var raindrop = raindrops[i];
     
     raindrop.y += 2.5;
     
     if (raindrop.y > canvasHeight) {
      raindrop.x = Math.random() * canvasWidth;
      raindrop.y = 0;
     }
    }
    
    // Render
    
    // Clear the canvas
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    // Draw the background
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,backgroundBuffer);
    
    // We use this function to tell WebGL how to interpret the data in the current buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
     aPositionLocation, // attribute index, usually just the order they were declared in the vertex shader
     2, // Number of values in attribute, vec2 has two floats
     gl.FLOAT, // The kind of data to be expected in the buffer
     false, // Telling WebGL we don't want the data to get normalized to 0.0 -> 1.0
     Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 4, // This is the size of a complete vertex in bytes (2 vec2's so four floats)
     Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 0 // This is the 'offset', or the number of floats that come before this attribute in each vertex. aPosition comes first so it's zero
    );
    
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
     aUVLocation,
     2,
     gl.FLOAT,
     false,
     Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 4,
     Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 2 // aUV comes second, so it's offset is two floats
    );
    
    // Tell WebGL we want to turn these attributes on for rendering
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aUVLocation);
    
    // Attach our background texture so the sampler2D can use it
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,backgroundTexture);
    
    // Attach our program we want to render with
    gl.useProgram(backgroundProgram);
    
    // Tell WebGL to start rendering!
    gl.drawArrays(
     gl.TRIANGLES, // Takes groups of 3 verticies to draw one complete triangle
     0, // Start at index 0 in our buffer
     6 // Use six complete verticies (whole sets of attributes) to draw 2 triangles
    );
    
    // We no longer need the background buffer, program or texture
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,null);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(aUVLocation);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
    gl.useProgram(null);
    
    // Draw raindrops
    // Since we're going to pass coordinates through uniforms, this can be done without a buffer
    
    // Bind texture for sampler2D
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,raindropTexture);
    
    // After attaching a program, we can upload values to uniforms using the values we got before from getUniformLocation()
    gl.useProgram(raindropProgram);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < raindrops.length; ++i) {
     var raindrop = raindrops[i];
     
     // Upload position
     gl.uniform2f(
      uRaindropPosition,
      convertXCoordinate(raindrop.x),
      convertYCoordinate(raindrop.y)
     );
     
     // Upload size
     gl.uniform1f(
      uRaindropSize,
      raindrop.size
     );
     
     gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS,0,1);
    }
    
    //
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
   
   // This gets called when the page finishes loading
   onload = function() {
    // Get the canvas
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    
    // Don't forget the webgl context!
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    
    // Create our program, it's made up of two smaller programs.
    // One processes verticies (one whole set of attributes) & one that decides the colour of each pixel
    // These smaller programs need to be created, compiled then attached to the main program
    
    // modern Javascript has a nice feature called string templates, if we use `` instead of "" we can
    // write strings that can have multiple lines!
    backgroundProgram = createProgram(
     ` // Vertex Shader
      precision lowp float;
      
      // These values are filled from our buffer
      attribute vec2 aPosition;
      attribute vec2 aUV;
      
      // Anything passed to this variable gets interpolated across any
      // pixels inside our triangle
      varying vec2 vUV;
      
      void main() {
       vUV = aUV;
       gl_Position = vec4(aPosition,0.0,1.0);
      }
      
     `,` // Fragment shader
      precision lowp float;
      
      // Freshly interpolated value from our vertex shader
      varying vec2 vUV;
      
      // A uniform is a variable shared between webgl & javascript
      // A sampler2D is a special datatype we use with texture2D
      // to get a single pixel from the texture that's currently
      // attached to TEXTURE_2D
      uniform sampler2D uTexture;
      
      void main() {
       gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture,vUV);
      }
     `
    );
    
    raindropProgram = createProgram(
     ` // Vertex shader
      precision lowp float;
      
      attribute vec2 aPosition;
      
      uniform vec2 uRaindropPosition;
      uniform float uRaindropSize;
      
      void main() {
       gl_PointSize = uRaindropSize;
       gl_Position = vec4(uRaindropPosition + aPosition,0.0,1.0);
      }
     `,` // Fragment shader
      precision lowp float;
      
      uniform sampler2D uTexture;
      
      void main() {
       gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture,gl_PointCoord);
       
       // Discard the pixel if it has no alpha
       if (gl_FragColor.a == 0.0) {
        discard;
       }
      }
     `
    );
    
    // Get the 'location' of uniform variables in our raindrop program
    // These will be used later to upload new uniform values to the gpu
    uRaindropPosition = gl.getUniformLocation(raindropProgram,"uRaindropPosition");
    uRaindropSize = gl.getUniformLocation(raindropProgram,"uRaindropSize");
    
    /*
     Create and upload an array of data to the GPU,
     each line contains all the attribute that make up one
     vertex, here it's an x y coorinate for the position on the screen
     followed by another x y coordinate for the position of the texture that
     should be displayed at that corner (coordinates for textures are normally called UVs U = x, V = y)
     
     Below is a list of verticies that make up two triangles that forms a rectangle that covers the whole screen,
     triangles in WebGL should go in counter clockwise order
    */
    backgroundBuffer = createBuffer([
     // X    Y   U   V
     -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,0.0, // Top left
     -1.0,-1.0, 0.0,1.0, // Bottom left
      1.0, 1.0, 1.0,0.0, // Top right
      
      1.0, 1.0, 1.0,0.0, // Top right
     -1.0,-1.0, 0.0,1.0, // Top left
      1.0,-1.0, 1.0,1.0  // Bottom right
    ]);
    
    // Create & upload textures
    backgroundTexture = createTexture(images.background);
    raindropTexture = createTexture(images.raindrop);
    
    // Set clearcolour, when we want an empty canvas
    //            R   G   B   A
    gl.clearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0);
    
    // Create some randomly placed raindrops to simulate
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
     raindrops.push(
      new Raindrop(
       Math.random() * canvasWidth,
       Math.random() * canvasHeight,
       25.0
      )
     );
    }
    
    loop();
   }
   
   // Called when the page is reloading or getting closed
   onunload = function() {
    gl.deleteProgram(backgroundProgram);
    gl.deleteProgram(raindropProgram);
    gl.deleteBuffer(backgroundBuffer);
    gl.deleteTexture(backgroundTexture);
    gl.deleteTexture(raindropTexture);
   }
   
  }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```